# How can i add custom build steps in Qt-Creator?

Tags: qt, build-process, qt-creator

After build my app, i want copy it to specific directory (on Windows 7).

Custom build step

```
cmd.exe \c \k copy MyPlugin.dll ..\..\..\HostApp\Debug\plugins
```

But I have error:

```
Can't run process "cmd.exe \c \k copy MyPlugin.dll ..\..\..\HostApp\Debug\plugins"
```

That's wrong?

Comment: Where exactly is located the cmd.exe command. In the Makefile, .pro file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it would be to change the build output directory in the .pro file.
Something like

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    DESTDIR = C:/myApp/debug
} else {
    DESTDIR = C:/myApp/release
}
```

Or in your particular case

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    DESTDIR = ..\..\..\HostApp\Debug\plugins
} else {
    DESTDIR = ..\..\..\HostApp\Release\plugins
}
```

Edit:
This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580934/how-to-specify-different-debug-release-output-directories-in-qmake-pro-file) has some good alternatives to my answer.