# How to change Debug/Release output dir using qmake .pro file. Cross-plataform

Tags: qt, cross-platform, qmake

I've read all post about it and none of solutions works in windows and linux. My current solution works pretty well in Windows, creating, if doesn't exist, the respective directory for debug or release.

I want to create all my object  files (*.o) inside one of these folders. In windows I achieved this in linux my DESTDIR variable is empty. =|

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = 
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
HEADERS += Config.h \
           keyboard.h \
           keyboardgui.h \
           keyboardkey.h \
           Log.h \
           main.h \
           mainwindow.h \
           Settings.h
FORMS += mainwindow.ui
SOURCES += Config.cpp \
           keyboard.cpp \
           keyboardgui.cpp \
           keyboardkey.cpp \
           Log.cpp \
           main.cpp \
           mainwindow.cpp
RESOURCES += Resources.qrc

OTHER_FILES += \
    default_layout.kl


# se for Windows
win32 {
# inclui a lib para acessar o DMI
LIBS += -lqaxcontainer
}

# Habilita a opcao de copia de diretorios
CONFIG += copy_dir_files

Debug:DESTDIR = debug
Release:DESTDIR = release

# copia a pasta configuracao para o diretorio de saida
win32 {
 QMAKE_POST_LINK +=  copy /Y default_layout.kl $$DESTDIR
}
else {
 QMAKE_POST_LINK +=  cp -a default_layout.kl $$DESTDIR 
}
```

I tried to use the INSTALL var but without success. The debug directory is created and all object files is put there but when I changed the compilation mode to RELEASE the objects files continue to be moved to the debug directory and the RELEASE directory isn't created (I've tried to run qmake again). In both configurations my files (default_layout and layout) aren't copied to the output directory.

```
# Habilita a opcao de copia de diretorios
CONFIG += copy_dir_files

release:DESTDIR = release
release:OBJECTS_DIR = release/
release:MOC_DIR = release/
release:RCC_DIR = release/
release:UI_DIR = release/

debug:DESTDIR = debug
debug:OBJECTS_DIR = debug/
debug:MOC_DIR = debug/
debug:RCC_DIR = debug/
debug:UI_DIR = debug/

INSTALLS += config_files
config_files.path = $$DESTDIR
config_files.filename = default_layout.kl
config_files.filename += layout.kl
```

thx!

Comment: Can probably be marked as a dupe now that so much time has passed: [How to specify different Debug/Release output directories in QMake .pro file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580934/how-to-specify-different-debug-release-output-directories-in-qmake-pro-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the reason it works on Windows and not on Linux is because you capitalized "Debug" and "Release".  The examples I have found all have them as lower case (see second example in this section on the [qmake document page](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7-snapshot/qmake-advanced-usage.html#scopes-and-conditions).)

The other thing I question is the use of DESTDIRS.  DESTDIRS tells qmake where you want to put the TARGET.  If you want to directly control where only the object files are put, you should use [OBJECT_DIRS](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7-snapshot/qmake-variable-reference.html#objects-dir).

Personally, I use qmake's [INSTALLS](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7-snapshot/qmake-environment-reference.html#installs) keyword to do copy extra files where they need to go.  It does mean executing both a `make` and a `make install`, but it does produce a more platform dependent code.

If I assume you want the TARGET and the objects in 'debug' or 'release', I would do it like this:

```
# Habilita a opcao de copia de diretorios
debug {
    DESTDIR = debug
    OBJ_DIR = debug
}
release
{
    DESTDIR = release
    OBJ_DIR = release
}

# copia a pasta configuracao para o diretorio de saida
config_files.path = $$DESTDIR
config_files.files = default_layout.kl
INSTALLS += config_files
```

If you are running QtCreator, you can add the `make install` step to the building settings by selecting the "Projects" icon in the left hand tool bar.  Next, select "Add Build Step", "Make", and set the "Make arguments" to `install`.  You will have to do this for each build configuration.

Comment: I did what you said, I've edited my post with the results. One more question, I need to execute make install in bash to get the results right ? Do you know how I can do the same in QtCreator and its build steps ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with one way to add `make install` to the build process in QtCreator.

Comment: @MaikoID  I see two issues in your revised qmake file. First, you should change "config_files._filename_" to "config_files._files_".  The second is that the INSTALLS line should be after you define config_files, not before.