# Specify debug/release build in qt

Tags: qt

I would like Qt Creator to build the project according to the type I specify in the little computer button.

Using:

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release)
{
    DESTDIR = Debug
    OBJECTS_DIR = Debug/.obj
    MOC_DIR = Debug/.moc
    RCC_DIR = Debug/.rcc
    UI_DIR = Debug/.ui
}

CONFIG(release, debug|release)
{
    DESTDIR = Release
    OBJECTS_DIR = Release/.obj
    MOC_DIR = Release/.moc
    RCC_DIR = Release/.rcc
    UI_DIR = Release/.ui
}
```

Or, using the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580934/how-to-specify-different-debug-release-output-directories-in-qmake-pro-file), makes qmake chose the last time a variable was defined.

How do I set it?

Thnx

P.S I don't know if it has something to do with my problem, but I'm using Ubuntu and not Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The opening brace should be on the same line as the condition, as indicated [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmake-advanced-usage.html#syntax).

Comment: OMG Seriously?! That's the solution, isn't it kinda dumb??? I feel really stupid right now =D. Thnx