# Change source directory and working directory depending on release type

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am using Qt and from reading other questions on here such as: [How to specify different Debug/Release output directories in QMake .pro file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580934/how-to-specify-different-debug-release-output-directories-in-qmake-pro-file) I have been able to change where the build files go.

Is it correct here that you have to manually edit the .pro file and also I cannot see a way to change the working directory that is used on the different releases.

I look on the Projects tab and there is a Run settings but the working directory on here is the same for both debug and release configurations. Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to edit the .pro file to change the directories where the build files go. (*C'mon, it's not that much work!*) :-)

If you enable the "shadow build" option, your working directory will automatically change as you go between debug and release builds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, not much work as you said it was rather that if there was a different way to do it that didn't involve changing the files as sometimes changing auto-generated files causes all sorts of havok. I will try the shadow build option, I wasn't totally sure what it did but I can read up on that