# Qt Creator ignores breakpoint

Tags: debugging, qt4, qt-creator, breakpoints

I created a simple console application in Qt. Here is source code of it:

[image]

When I use function Debug -> Start Debugging -> Start Debugging from the main menu, application runs and print the message "Hello world" to the console. But debugger ignores breakpoint set on line 6 (as you can see from the above screenshot).

Additional informations:
QT Creator version - 2.4.1
QT library version - 4.8.1 (but there is also 4.7.4 installed in separate directory)

Project Build Settings are as follows:

[image]

Tool Chain settings in Tools -> Options:

[image]

GDB executable is present at directory "E:\QtSDK\pythongdb\python_2.7based" which is underlined by the fact that I have no problem debugging similarly GUI based Hello World program.

GDB settings:

[image]

Is there something I am doing wrong?

P.S. Here is my compile output:

[image]

Here is content of Makefile.debug:

#######################################################################

## Makefile for building: PasswordGuess

## Generated by qmake (2.01a) (Qt 4.8.1) on: ne 28. 4 18:12:57 2013

## Project:  ..\PasswordGuess\PasswordGuess.pro

## Template: app

#######################################################################

# Compiler, tools and options

CC            = gcc
CXX           = g++
DEFINES       = -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT
CFLAGS        = -g -Wall $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I"......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\include\QtCore" -I"......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\include" -I"......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"..\PasswordGuess" -I"." -I"......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\win32-g++"
LINK        =        g++
LFLAGS        =        -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads
LIBS        =        -L"e:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\lib" -lQtCored4
QMAKE         = e:\qtsdk\desktop\qt\4.8.1\mingw\bin\qmake.exe
IDC           = e:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\bin\idc.exe
IDL           = midl
ZIP           = zip -r -9
DEF_FILE      =
RES_FILE      =
COPY          = copy /y
SED           =
COPY_FILE     = $(COPY)
COPY_DIR      = xcopy /s /q /y /i
DEL_FILE      = del
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = move
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= if not exist
MKDIR         = mkdir
INSTALL_FILE    = $(COPY_FILE)
INSTALL_PROGRAM = $(COPY_FILE)
INSTALL_DIR     = $(COPY_DIR)

# Output directory

OBJECTS_DIR   = debug

# Files

SOURCES       = ..\PasswordGuess\main.cpp
OBJECTS       = debug/main.o
DIST          =
QMAKE_TARGET  = PasswordGuess
DESTDIR        = debug\ #avoid trailing-slash linebreak
TARGET         = PasswordGuess.exe
DESTDIR_TARGET = debug\PasswordGuess.exe

# Implicit rules

.SUFFIXES: .cpp .cc .cxx .c

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o $@ $<

.cc.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o $@ $<

.cxx.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o $@ $<

.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o $@ $<

# Build rules

first: all
all: Makefile.Debug  $(DESTDIR_TARGET)

$(DESTDIR_TARGET):  $(OBJECTS)
    $(LINK) $(LFLAGS) -o $(DESTDIR_TARGET) $(OBJECTS)  $(LIBS)

qmake:  FORCE
    @$(QMAKE) -spec ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\win32-g++ CONFIG+=declarative_debug -o Makefile.Debug ..\PasswordGuess\PasswordGuess.pro

dist:
    $(ZIP) PasswordGuess.zip $(SOURCES) $(DIST) ..\PasswordGuess\PasswordGuess.pro ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\qconfig.pri ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\modules\qt_webkit_version.pri ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\qt_functions.prf ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\qt_config.prf ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\exclusive_builds.prf ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\default_pre.prf ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\win32\default_pre.prf ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\debug.prf ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\debug_and_release.prf ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\default_post.prf ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\win32\default_post.prf ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\build_pass.prf ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\win32\console.prf ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\declarative_debug.prf ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\win32\rtti.prf ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\win32\exceptions.prf ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\win32\stl.prf ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\shared.prf ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\warn_on.prf ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\qt.prf ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\win32\thread.prf ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\moc.prf ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\resources.prf ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\uic.prf ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\yacc.prf ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\lex.prf ......\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\mkspecs\features\include_source_dir.prf  HEADERS RESOURCES IMAGES SOURCES OBJECTIVE_SOURCES FORMS YACCSOURCES YACCSOURCES LEXSOURCES

clean: compiler_clean
    -$(DEL_FILE) debug\main.o

distclean: clean
    -$(DEL_FILE) $(DESTDIR_TARGET)
    -$(DEL_FILE) Makefile.Debug

check: first

mocclean: compiler_moc_header_clean compiler_moc_source_clean

mocables: compiler_moc_header_make_all compiler_moc_source_make_all

compiler_moc_header_make_all:
compiler_moc_header_clean:
compiler_rcc_make_all:
compiler_rcc_clean:
compiler_image_collection_make_all: qmake_image_collection.cpp
compiler_image_collection_clean:
    -$(DEL_FILE) qmake_image_collection.cpp
compiler_moc_source_make_all:
compiler_moc_source_clean:
compiler_uic_make_all:
compiler_uic_clean:
compiler_yacc_decl_make_all:
compiler_yacc_decl_clean:
compiler_yacc_impl_make_all:
compiler_yacc_impl_clean:
compiler_lex_make_all:
compiler_lex_clean:
compiler_clean:

# Compile

debug/main.o: ../PasswordGuess/main.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o debug\main.o ..\PasswordGuess\main.cpp

# Install

install:   FORCE

uninstall:   FORCE

FORCE:

Answer (score 5):

**Disable the flag *Run in terminal*** under *Projects->Run*.

Once disabled this option, the project can be still succesfully debugged with the console output shown on the bottom panel of Qt Creator.

Answer (score 2):

**SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)** added this line to **CMakeLists.txt** in case of Linux. For windows you need to set **Debug** keyword in .pro file.

Else you can also simply set cmake command **-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug** which is the best solution.

Refer [.pro file settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580934/how-to-specify-different-debug-release-output-directories-in-qmake-pro-file)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your application is built without debugging information. Make sure you're building the Debug configuration and that -g flag is used (if you're using MinGW).

Comment: I added compiler output and makefile content to issue to asses this option.