# How to set output directory for QMake generated vcproj files

Tags: qmake

Is there anyway to modify the path where *.vcproj (and *.vcxproj, *.sln...) files generated by QMake are written ?

I do not want to modify the path of the generated *.exe or *.dll file. I'm looking for a way to create the *.vcproj file out of my sources directory, to keep it clean from any generated file.

I'm using Qt 5.5.

Thanks

**EDIT :**

By default, QMake generate a *.sln/*.vcproj file next to the *.pro file (in the same directory). I'm looking for a way to generate the *.sln/*.vcproj file elsewhere.

Comment: maybe this helps: [How to specify different Debug/Release output directories in QMake .pro file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580934/how-to-specify-different-debug-release-output-directories-in-qmake-pro-file)

Comment: I'm trying to set the directory where the vcproj file is written, not where the binary files are built

Comment: I don't get it. The sln and vcproj files belong to the build dir, so if you modify their location you also change the location of the build files. The accepted answer in the link I provided shows how to set up qmake for an out of source build.

Comment: The output location of the binary built by a vcproj file is a configuration parameter of the vcproj file. Your link, and many others, explain how to configure this using QMake. I'm not looking for this. See my edit in the question.

Comment: but you have tried the [-o commandline option](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-running.html)?

Comment: I've tried it, but since I use a "SUBDIRS" template (my solution is made with 3 EXE and 5 DLL), it only output the main "*.sln" file elsewhere, not the *.vcproj files.